# configuring Nginx to run flask automatically with uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am developing python programs and I have a flask file which runs them. Now I am trying to run flask automatically from Nginx and linking them with uWSGI. It's not working and getting stuck.

I followed this page.here is the link: https://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/
I have performed all the necessary steps and got 502 bad gateway error.
while executing

```
uswgi  --ini /var/www/tg/tg_uswgi.ini
```

I am getting the following

```
[uSWGI] getting INI configuration from /var/www/tg/tg_uwsgi.ini
```

after this, I am not getting anything.when i run my server, it still gives me 502 Bad gateway.

this is my 
tg_nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location / { try_files $uri @yourapplication; }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/tg/tg_uwsgi.sock;
    }    
}
```

this is my tg_uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/tg

#python module to import
app = fileforflk     //fileforflk is my flask file which calls other python 
                    //files
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /var/www/demoapp/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

this is my flask file

```
from flask import Flask
import browser          //python file the flask is calling
app = Flask(_name_)
@app.route('/test',methods= ['GET'])
def result():
   return ("success")
if _name_ == '_main_':
   app.run(host = '0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

After getting INI configuration, the terminal is not showing anything and the server still returns bad gateway. please help me with this.

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':` note the double underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define:

```
socket = /var/www/demoapp/%n.sock
```

And :

```
uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/tg/tg_uwsgi.sock;
```

should be matching. So for example, define:

```
socket = /var/www/tg/%n.sock
```

And :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/tg/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/uwsgi/
```

Comment: I have changed it from demoapp to tg. still getting stuck at the terminal.it says `[uSWGI] getting INI configuration from /var/www/tg/tg_uwsgi.ini` and no results.

Comment: does any  have `*.sock` file in `/var/www/tg/` ?

Comment: I have a tg_uwsgi.sock file in /var/www/tg/

Comment: In nginx error log, I am getting `connect() to Unix:/var/www/tg/tg_uwsgi.sock failed (13: permission Denied) while connecting to upstream`

Comment: so `chown` `nginx:nginx` or `www-data:www-data`  for `/var/www/tg/tg_uwsgi.sock` , just updated the answer

Comment: used  `chown` and changed permissions, now getting `connect() to Unix:/var/www/tg/tg_uwsgi.sock failed (111 : connection refused) while connecting upstream`.

Comment: In  Uwsgi error log, I am getting no module called 'encodings'. PythonHome is set correctly to /var/www/tg/venv where venv is my virtual environment folder.please help me out with this.

Comment: `pip install encodings` please create new question if this is done.